# How can I view transactions within a specific date range?

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk, java-sdk, stellar-laboratory

### Is there any solution for filtering transactions by date?

**Scenario: I wanna fetch transactions for a specific account in a specific range of date like 2020/04/04 to 2020/05/04**

I looked for it a lot in APIs in the laboratory but did not find anything!

It's pretty critical if we have clients that want their report of transactions by a range of the date!

Answer (score 0):

The Horizon endpoint [Transactions for Account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-for-account.html) takes a `cursor` argument that allows you to set the start of the transaction range. There is no end of range argument because a single response is limited in the maximum number of entries, so you may need to make multiple calls (using the returned `next` link) to receive all the available data. Once you receive the page that crosses your end time, you can use the `created_at` field to identify the last transaction in your range.

Comment: What you mean is we must search between transactions until we find the proper paging token for corresponding date? then we can index that paging token for that date range.
In this case, we must surely create a batch job for index paging token by created_time 
 for all transactions for future searches.